# how to disable WORD WRAP in python IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, word-wrap

I’m trying to print a string that is too long to be displayed on one line, so it automatically wraps to the next line. The problem is that I need it to all stay on one line and just go off the screen (where I can just scroll left to right to see it all).Is there a way to to disable word wrap in python IDLE
by changing somethings in configure option

Comment: This is due to how your terminal is configured and has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: What is the coding environment you are using?

Comment: Note that most terminal do *not* have the ability to scroll horizontally. Once the text is wrapped, if you try to resize horizontally the text wont change. The terminal size increases but with unfilled background.

Comment: `log = open("log.txt","w");print >> log , "a " + "really "*100 + "long string";`  will demonstrate that text does not wrap

Comment: How useful this cheat is will depend on your problem, but you can sometimes get around this by just making window wider than your screen and letting the right edge go off the screen. (I have to drag the window so that the left side is off screen, then pull the right side to reach to the right side of the screen, and repeat as much as necessary, then gradually pull the window back until the left edge is on screen again.)

Answer (score 6):

Text wrapping is a function of your **terminal**, not python. All that python does is send a string to the terminal - think about it, when you say `print "abcdef\n"`, there's no character in there that tells the terminal to wrap-text!

You just need to configure the environment you're coding in. There should be a pretty easily accessible 'settings' option. However, if you can't find it, then tell us what environment you're using - we might be able to help.

Comment: That's why he's asking about IDLE, not python.